# docker-compose: directory permission errors on bind mount

Tags: docker, permissions, docker-compose, prometheus

Trying to spin up a `docker-compose` stack with a `prometheus` image (although the actual service is rather irrelevant.

I have created the following dir to persist `prometheus` data.

```
$ ls -ald /prometheus_data/
drwxrwxr-x 3 root root 4096 Jan 17 07:24 /prometheus_data/
```

and set up the service in `docker-compose` as follows:

```
prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    volumes:
        - ./prometheus/:/etc/prometheus/
        - /prometheus_data:/prometheus_data:rw
    command:
        - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
        - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus_data'
        - '--storage.tsdb.retention=4d'
        - '--web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries'
        - '--web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles'
    ports:
        - 9090:9090
    depends_on:
        - cadvisor
    restart: always
```

However the service fails:

```
prometheus_1     | level=error ts=2019-01-17T09:35:09.200050622Z caller=main.go:579 err="Opening storage failed open DB in /prometheus_data: open /prometheus_data/146791472: permission denied"
prometheus_1     | level=info ts=2019-01-17T09:35:09.20007784Z caller=main.go:581 msg="See you next time!"
```

Isn't the service initiated by the `root` user?

Why its gets the above permission errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/Dockerfile) of `prometheus` the `USER` is set to `nobody`.

So it makes sense that the above dir is not accessible by the service.

So the problem was solved by performing a

```
chgrp -R nogroup /prometheus_data
```

Comment: There seems to be some concern regarding whether nobody:nogroup is appropriate for use: https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3441. I have no opinion on the matter but you can execute the container as a different user/group (e.g. 1234:5678) and set the file system to the same permissions.

Comment: How did you issue command in your docker-compose file?