# Permission denied on /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml; cannot deploy prom/prometheus

Tags: docker, ansible, prometheus, nfs

I'm using an NFS mount to provide the `/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml` (default) config file to prom/prometheus docker image all via Ansible. When the container is deployed, I'm getting the following error in the container logs, and the container restarts after a few seconds.

`level=error ts=2020-10-28T16:01:04.432Z caller=main.go:290 msg="Error loading config (--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml)" err="open /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml: permission denied"`

I can browse the mounted filesystem on my docker host (a Raspberry Pi 4), touch files and read `prometheus.yml` as the user that launches the container.

Below are the relevant tasks from my playbook, and the issue is the same when deploying the container from the CLI *without* the playbook with the remote filesystem mounted to at `/mnt/prometheus`, and passed to the container as a volume at `/etc/prometheus`

`docker run -p 9090:9090 -v /mnt/prometheus:/etc/prometheus prom/prometheus`

**prometheus/tasks/main.yml** (`become: yes` is set in the playbook that calls this role)

```
  - name: "Create mountpoint"
    file: 
        path: "{{ prometheus_mount_path }}"
        state: directory
        mode: 0777
        owner: root
        group: users
        

  - name: "Mount nfs drive for prometheus filesystem"
    mount: 
        path: "{{ prometheus_mount_path }}"
        src: "{{ nfs_server }}:{{ prometheus_nfs_path }}"
        state: mounted
        fstype: nfs
        
  - name: "Create prometheus.yml in mountpoint from template"
    template: 
        src: prometheus.yml.j2
        dest: "{{ prometheus_mount_path }}/prometheus.yml"

        
  - name: "Deploy prometheus container"
    docker_container:
        name: prometheus
        image: prom/prometheus:latest
        restart_policy: always
        state: started
        network_mode: host
        hostname: prometheus
#        exposed_ports: 9090
        published_ports: 9090:9090
        user: 995:1002
        mounts: 
        volumes:
            - "{{ prometheus_mount_path }}:/etc/prometheus"
        comparisons:
            '*': ignore
            env: strict
```

Any idea what would cause or how to resolve the `permission denied` issue from the container?

**Update:** I tested by sharing a directory on the docker host with the container. This was successfully shared. Points to an NFS issue, but I'm struggling to figure that out.

Comment: Can you post the output for `ls -l /mnt/prometheus` on the host? You are setting `user: 995:1002`, so have you already set the correct permissions using `chown 995:1002 ...`?

Comment: jehan@cluster1:~ $ ls -l /mnt/prometheus/
 total 8
 -rwxrwxrwx 1 nobody root  681 Oct 26 20:28  prometheus.yml
 d--------- 3 nobody root 4096 Oct 25 04:25 '#recycle

I haven't set perms after mounting, just set the perms as in the playbook.

Comment: Try this docker run -p 9090:9090 -v /mnt/prometheus:/etc/prometheus:Z prom/prometheus

Comment: Try to mount it using Z or z, since at some point the volume got different containers labels on it.

Comment: @Ashok same issue. Reading up on the Z/z flags, I don't think they apply on this OS. Believe they only apply on selinux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my particular case, I found the issue was a function of NFS squashing. My NFS exporter - an older Synology NAS -  didn't allow me to disable squashing entirely. If it had, @nehtor.t's answer probably would have helped. Instead I had to use the "map all users to admin" setting in the NFS GUI, which allowed connections the appropriate permissions on the NFS share to appropriately `chown`.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, although not with NFS but with mounting a simple directory. For me the answer in this question fixed it: [docker-compose: directory permission errors on bind mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54232891/docker-compose-directory-permission-errors-on-bind-mount).

Apparently Prometheus Docker is using the user `nobody`, setting folder permissions to `nogroup` worked for me:

```
chgrp -R nogroup /mnt/prometheus
```

So in your Ansible playbook:

```
- name: fix permissions for prometheus mnt folder
  file:
    path: '/mnt/prometheus'
    group: nogroup
    recurse: yes
  become: yes
```

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, your post would have helped me along. In my case, it was a function of NFS Squashing. My NFS server (A Synology NAS) didn't allow me to disable squashing, so I squashed all users to admin.